# Get photos from Iphone photo gallery with UIImagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm going to build an app that uploads my photos and videos in my gallery, to an FTP-server every midnight. This app isn't going into app store. I just going to link to my .IPA-file and install it like that.

However, I have read that `UIImagepickercontroller` requires user interaction, but I want to build this app like an hidden services. Does `UIImagepickercontroller` allow me to get the images & videos without any user interaction?

**If not, is there an API that lets me do that?**

Comment: It will show user permission alert to access photos when app trying to access photos from device gallery.

Comment: @Kampai: As I asked in my question, does it exist any API that allow me to do this kind of "hidden" service without any user interaction?

Comment: @KlimczakM: Can't I customize an image picker controller to manage user interactions myself?

Comment: Sounds like you want ALAssetsLibrary. It lets you enumerate your assets from your photo library and display it without user interaction. Question I got for you is, why do you want to upload your image gallery every midnight?

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController requires user interaction, there is no way to get them without user interaction.

Comment: So It is impossible to develop this kind of app as an hidden service?

Comment: Can't I customize an image picker controller to manage user interactions myself?

Comment: i haven't gone into the api enough to see if that is possible but from my previous experiences it looks like the only way is user interaction. Maybe there is a way by getting the folder structure of photos but im not sure.

Comment: Can't I use the Assets Library?

Comment: try this: http://five.agency/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/